# Multi-class classification with only one feature

Tags: feature-selection, multiclass-classification

I am studying the efficacy of using a single feature for predicting a set of events (which is a multi-class classification problem). I was wondering if it makes any sense to use **only one feature** for multi-class classification. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes! You can use only one feature for multi-class classification. For example, you have one feature `height` and you want to classify `short` , `medium` or `tall`.